# Regularization and scaling feature matrix with weights

Tags: regression, scikit-learn, standardization, glmnet, weighted-regression

When using L1 or L2 regularization in a glm it is necessary to standardize the features to be variance 1. When applying weights to the glm, should the feature matrix be standardized so that it has a **weighted** variance of 1?

According to the glmnet paper
https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/glmnet.pdf
There is no mention of standardizing to have weighted variance 1. Furthermore, there is a simplification in the unweighted case that's made in equation 8 where the authors took advantage of the fact that column j had variance 1. When they describe the weighted case, they do not make any simplification taking advantage of column j having weighted variance 1. This makes it sound like standardization always happens without weights.

When I went through the source code of ElasticNet in sklearn I was unable to find references to weights

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/linear_model/coordinate_descent.py#L503

This doesn't seem to be correct. If I have a data frame with 2 identical rows, they will contribute twice to the mean and variance. This can be equivalently represented as one row with a weight of 2, but if weights are ignored in standardization the algorithm will have a different result

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "applying weights to the glm". Are you referring to adaptive/weighted regularization using a vector of regularization parameters?

Comment: Weights as in weighted likelihood